# how insert name of files in column in R

Tags: r, dplyr

suppose, i have such files

```
rock=structure(list(x1 = c(0, 0.8, 0.4, 0.3, 0.5, 1, 0.7, 0.6, 0.4, 
0.4, 0.6), x2 = c(0, 1, 0.5, 0.3, 0.5, 0.5, 0.8, 0.3, 0.6, 0.8, 
0.7), x3 = c(0, 0.4, 0.8, 0.4, 0.2, 1, 0.5, 0.8, 0.4, 1, 0.3), 
    x4 = c(0, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.8, 0.3, 0.7, 0.6, 0.2
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
rave=structure(list(x1 = c(0, 0.8, 0.4, 0.3, 0.5, 1), x2 = c(0, 1, 
0.5, 0.3, 0.5, 0.5), x3 = c(0, 0.4, 0.8, 0.4, 0.2, 1), x4 = c(0, 
0.3, 0.4, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
classic=structure(list(x1 = c(0, 0.8), x2 = 0:1, x3 = c(0, 0.4), x4 = c(0, 
0.3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

How to do that when i `rbind` these datasets, for each dataset paste original name
I.e the result i want to see this like this. Initial data with names in csv format. For example

```
classic=read.csv(path to classic.csv)

   dataset  x1  x2  x3  x4
1  classic 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
2  classic 0.8 1.0 0.4 0.3
3     Rave 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
4     Rave 0.8 1.0 0.4 0.3
5     Rave 0.4 0.5 0.8 0.4
6     Rave 0.3 0.3 0.4 0.4
7     Rave 0.5 0.5 0.2 0.5
8     rock 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
9     rock 0.8 1.0 0.4 0.3
10    rock 0.4 0.5 0.8 0.4
11    rock 0.3 0.3 0.4 0.4
12    rock 0.5 0.5 0.2 0.5
13    rock 1.0 0.5 1.0 0.6
14    rock 0.7 0.8 0.5 0.8
15    rock 0.6 0.3 0.8 0.3
16    rock 0.4 0.6 0.4 0.7
17    rock 0.4 0.8 1.0 0.6
18    rock 0.6 0.7 0.3 0.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put them in a list and use `bind_rows` :

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(lst(rock, rave, classic), .id = 'dataset')

#   dataset  x1  x2  x3  x4
#1     rock 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
#2     rock 0.8 1.0 0.4 0.3
#3     rock 0.4 0.5 0.8 0.4
#4     rock 0.3 0.3 0.4 0.4
#5     rock 0.5 0.5 0.2 0.5
#6     rock 1.0 0.5 1.0 0.6
#7     rock 0.7 0.8 0.5 0.8
#8     rock 0.6 0.3 0.8 0.3
#9     rock 0.4 0.6 0.4 0.7
#10    rock 0.4 0.8 1.0 0.6
#11    rock 0.6 0.7 0.3 0.2
#12    rave 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
#13    rave 0.8 1.0 0.4 0.3
#14    rave 0.4 0.5 0.8 0.4
#15    rave 0.3 0.3 0.4 0.4
#16    rave 0.5 0.5 0.2 0.5
#17    rave 1.0 0.5 1.0 0.6
#18 classic 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
#19 classic 0.8 1.0 0.4 0.3
```

---

However, it would be better if you could read the data in a list automatically without reading them individually first.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

filenames <- list.files('/path/to/csv', pattern = '\\.csv', full.names = TRUE)

result <- map_df(filenames, 
                 ~read.csv(.x) %>% 
                   mutate(dataset = tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(.x))))
```

Comment: is the way automatically put names of csv files. Without lst?

Comment: You can add a new column while reading the csv file. Does the updated answer help?

Comment: yes, it help, thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can add a column with a constant name to your datasets then
rbind and then put last column to first position

```
classic['dataset'] = 'classic'
rave['dataset'] = 'rave'
rock['dataset'] = 'rock'
df <- rbind(classic, rave, rock)
df <- df[,c(ncol(df), 1:ncol(df)-1)]
```